# Theorem 6.12(a) Of Baby Rudin. Alternative Proof Of $ \int_a^b \left( f_1 + f_2 \right) d \alpha = \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> If $f_1 \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ and $f_2 \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$, then
> $$ \int_a^b \left( f_1 + f_2 \right) d \alpha = \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha$$

I want to prove this theorem using definition of integral(upper and lower Riemann-Stieltjes integral). We’ll make use of $ L(P, f_1, \alpha)+ L(P, f_2, \alpha) \leq L(P, f, \alpha) \leq U(P, f, \alpha) \leq U(P, f_1, \alpha) + U(P, f_2, \alpha )$ fact.

**My attempt:** let $f= f_{1} + f_{2}$.
$\inf U(P,f, \alpha) \leq U(P,f, \alpha) \leq U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)$. Since $\inf U(P,f, \alpha)$ is an lower bound of $U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)$, we have $\inf U(P,f, \alpha) \leq \inf \{U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)\}= \inf U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + \inf  U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)$. Similarly, $\sup L(P,f_{1},\alpha) + \sup L(P,f_{2},\alpha) \leq \sup L(P,f,\alpha)$.
Thus, $\sup L(P,f_{1},\alpha) + \sup L(P,f_{2},\alpha) \leq \sup L(P,f,\alpha) \leq \inf U(P,f, \alpha) \leq \inf U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + \inf U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)$. Since, $\sup L(P,f_{1},\alpha) = \inf U(P,f_{1}, \alpha)$ and $\sup L(P,f_{2},\alpha) = \inf U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)$, we have $ \sup L(P,f,\alpha) = \inf U(P,f, \alpha)= \inf U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + \inf U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)$. Our desired equality $\int_a^b \left( f_1 + f_2 \right) d \alpha = \int_a^b f_1 d \alpha + \int_a^b f_2 d \alpha$.

**Is this proof correct?**

Comment: @CBBAM I agree. I assume you are taking about the same proof given in Rudin’s book.

Comment: Have you already proven this? $$\inf \{U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)\}= \inf U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + \inf  U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring No. Not precisely.

Comment: @BrianMoehring is there anything wrong?

Comment: I think that equation is the main crux of the proof, so you'd need to prove it if you haven't already (else you risk begging the question).  Everything else is just accounting.

Comment: @BrianMoehring **Proof:** $\inf \{ \sum_{i=0}^n M_{i}(f_{1}) \Delta \alpha_{i} + \sum_{i=0}^n M_{i}(f_{2}) \Delta \alpha_{i} \} = \inf \{ \sum_{i=0}^n M_{i}(f_{1}) \Delta \alpha_{i} \} + \inf \{ \sum_{i=0}^n M_{i}(f_{2}) \Delta \alpha_{i} \} = \inf U(P,f_{1},\alpha) + \inf U(P,f_{2},\alpha) $ is this proof correct?

Comment: @BrianMoehring is above proof okay or is it over simplified?

Comment: That is hardly a step above stating the proof is "Obvious".  In general, we only have $$\inf_{I\in \mathcal{I}} (x_I + y_I) \geq \inf_{I\in \mathcal{I}}(x_I) + \inf_{I\in \mathcal{I}}(y_I)$$ but this inequality is the opposite of what you want.  You need to show that the opposite inequality holds in your particular case, which is likely to involve the lemma $$U(P\cup Q, f, \alpha) \leq U(P, f, \alpha)$$
at some point.

Comment: I used equality sign because of this  https://courses-archive.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/37488 Exercise 5(b)

Comment: That exercise cannot apply to the current question, so if that's why you used the equality sign, then you have an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You snuck in a major step right here that needs an explanation:
$$\inf \{U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)\}= \inf U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + \inf  U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)$$
We immediately have
$$\inf \{U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)\} \geq \inf U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + \inf  U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)$$
but in the context of the proof, this inequality is pointing in the wrong direction.  What we really need is the other direction.  That is, if we write $\mathcal{P}$ for the set of finite partitions of $[a,b]$, then for clarity, we need to show
$$\inf_{P \in \mathcal{P}} \Big(U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)\Big) \leq \inf_{P \in \mathcal{P}} U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + \inf_{P \in \mathcal{P}}  U(P,f_{2}, \alpha).$$

---

This follows easily from the lemma
$$P_1,P_2 \in \mathcal{P} \implies P_1\cup P_2 \in \mathcal{P} \text { and } U(P_1\cup P_2, f, \alpha) \leq U(P_i,f,\alpha) \text{ for } i=1,2$$
as then for any $P_1,P_2 \in \mathcal{P},$
$$\begin{align*}\inf_{P \in \mathcal{P}} \Big(U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)\Big) &\leq U(P_1\cup P_2,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P_1\cup P_2,f_{2}, \alpha) \\ &\leq U(P_1,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P_2,f_{2}, \alpha)\end{align*}$$
Now by taking the infimum over $P_1,P_2 \in \mathcal{P}$,
$$\begin{align*}\inf_{P \in \mathcal{P}} \Big(U(P,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P,f_{2}, \alpha)\Big) &\leq \inf_{P_1, P_2\in \mathcal{P}}\Big(U(P_1,f_{1}, \alpha) + U(P_2,f_{2}, \alpha)\Big) \\ &= \inf_{P_1\in \mathcal{P}}U(P_1,f_{1}, \alpha) + \inf_{P_2\in \mathcal{P}}U(P_2,f_{2}, \alpha) \end{align*}$$
[Note that this last equality is the exercise you wanted to use in the comments]

---

As for the lemma's proof, it should be simple to show $P_1\cup P_2 \in \mathcal{P}$.  For the inequality, you can induct on the size of $P_1\cup P_2$ to assume $|P_1 \cup P_2| = |P_1| + 1$, in which case the proof just amounts to showing that $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ implies
$$\sup_{x \in [x_1,x_3]}f(x)(\alpha(x_3)-\alpha(x_1)) \geq \sup_{x\in [x_1,x_2]}f(x)(\alpha(x_2)-\alpha(x_1)) + \sup_{x\in [x_2,x_3]}f(x)(\alpha(x_3)-\alpha(x_2))$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is the reason why I post my proofs (to double check) in this site.